# How to freeze a sprite for a certain amount of time in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Since importing the module "time" and using time.sleep(seconds) freezes the whole screen. How to freeze a sprite for 3, 4 or 5 seconds? I Tried doing this but it freezes the whole pygame for 3 seconds!

```
elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"freeze a sprite"_? To make it stop moving?

Comment: yes to freeze for a certain amount of time and be able to move other sprites.

Comment: Sprites are just images so it all depends on how you blit them. I don't know how your program works but I'm guessing your sprites has a velocity variable? The just set that variable to 0 on the sprite you want to freeze, have a timer check until a certain time has gone and then set the velocity back to the value it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pygame you are responsible for the "main loop", and therefore for all the time management of your game.

This is great for simple drawing examples, and great to "keep in control" of things - but that means that if are the sole responsble for everything that moves and updates on the screen.

When you call `pygame.time.delay` or `time.sleep` you pause the whole program - the only way of pausing a certain object and not others, and nt stopping responding events at all, is to build mechanisms in your code that allow for individual object pausing.

For simple code, it can be a simple "pause" attribute and an `if` verification in your sprite code - for example, given a "frame rate" of 30 updates per second - soemthng along this on your sprite class's `update` method, if you use that method to actual update the position and "take actions" with your object would be:

```
class MySprite(BaseSprite):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.pause = 0...

    def update(self):
        if self.pause:
            self.pause -= 1
            return 

def main():
   FRAMERATE = 30
   myobject = MySprite(...)

   while True:
       if ...:
           ...

       elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
             myobject.pause = 3 * FRAMERATE
       for obj in all_my_objs:
             obj.update()
```